# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './src/util/Constants.js' is not defined by \"exports\"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm having trouble while coding my discord bot. Whenever i run this code:

```
const Constants = require('discord.js/src/util/Constants.js')
Constants.DefaultOptions.ws.properties.$browser = `Discord iOS`
```

I kept getting this error.

```
  Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './src/util/Constants.js' is not defined by \"exports\" in /home/runner/VerifyBot/node_modules/discord.js/package.json
```

I'm using node v12.18.4 and discord.js v12.3.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, the subpath in your require statement is not defined in Discord JS' [package.json](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/package.json#L7-L16). If you want to get the Constants, you can do so by using the following line of code:

```js
const { Constants } = require('discord.js');
```

Alternatively, the following will work as well:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Constants = Discord.Constants;
```